# URL as a table name

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a JDBC MySQL database that has records with a unique string field, that string is a URL. Each URL needs to have a table named by that exact URL.

The issue: 
Some URL consist of more than 64 characters, that exceeds the maximum length of a table identifier ([MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)).
URL contains non permitted characters.

How should I handle this?
My thought was to find or create some kind of encoder that will follow limitations and act as a bijection function. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not using an additional table to store a mapping from a url to a table name? You can that use table names like table1, table2, ...

Comment: Except for this is a horrible idea, you can store the hash value, SHA1 generates exact 32 bytes so that you can represent it with 64 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming your tables as URLs is a horrible idea. Not only will you run into max name length issues, but also encoding issues and escape issues.

A better approach would be to generate automatic names (table1, table2 etc) and have an index table that maps a URL to the table created for it

Answer (score 0):

A table per URL?  No, that's silly.

You should have one table with URLs and another with 1:many relationship to it.  Your idea is not scalable.

I'd recommend that you not use a URL as primary key.

A better idea would be a auto generated key from the database and a UNIQUE constraint on the URL column.  Now your URL can be a CLOB if you wish.  Should not run afoul of any [length limitations](http://boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) that way.